# Vim - get output of EX mode into a variable

Tags: vim, ex

I'm writing a vim script where I need to get the first line of the current buffer. In Ex mode I can simply type `1` and it shows me the content I want.
How can I put the output of the ex command into a variable in vim?

Comment: Thank you for posting your motivation in addition to your problem; you've successfully avoided the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression you want is `getline(1)`. Thus, `let x = getline(1)`.

Answer (score 4):

Chris's answer is the right approach.

Note however, that you can use the `:redir` command to capture the output of an Ex command into a variable:

```
:let myvar = ""
:redir => myvar
:command
:redir END
```

See `:h :redir` for more information.

Comment: By ex mode I don't mean command mode of vim. I meant the mode when you press Q or gQ :)

Comment: Yes, I know what "Ex mode" is, what do you mean by "ex command", then?

Comment: In normal mode, press Q or gQ in vim. It will open the ex mode. There you'll have a different functionality

Comment: I know how Ex mode works, thanks. And I know what "ex command" means. You asked "How can I put the output of the **ex command** into a variable in vim?" don't you? That's exactly what I explained. Did you even try my suggestion? Also the purpose of `:1` is not to output the current line or even line 1, its purpose is to move to line 1. The content of the line is printed out to provide feedback. `:1p` is the command you should use if you want to print out the content of line 1 and `:redir => abc` is the command you need if you want to put that output into variable `abc`.